# Application logging broken under Tomcat 9: permission denied to /var/log/myapp

Tags: permissions, logging, log-files, file-permissions, tomcat9

I have a Java webapp that runs under Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu Linux.   When I upgraded from Tomcat 9 from Tomcat 8, the application was no longer able to write log files to `/var/log/myapp`.  I can't figure out why it doesn't have permission to log to this location.

My first thought was that the user changed.   Tomcat 8 ran under the `tomcat8:tomcat8` user.   Tomcat 9 runs under `tomcat:tomcat` user.   I updated the directory with those permissions.  Both the `tomcat` user and `tomcat` group have write permission.

I also checked the write and execute permissions of that directory.   That directory has write  and execute permissions, and all parent directories have execute permissions.

```
/var/log/myapp/ drwxrwxr-x  tomcat tomcat
/var/log        drwxrwxr-x  root syslog 
/var            drwxr-xr-x  root root            
/               drwxr-xr-x  root root
```

If I run the following code under my web application

```
    File logdir =  new File("/var/log/myapp");
    setAttribute("debug", 
        "<br>user: " + System.getProperty("user.name") +
        "<br>execute: " + logdir.canExecute() +
        "<br>read: " + logdir.canRead() +
        "<br>write: " + logdir.canWrite()
    );
```

it prints out that there is no write permission

```
user: tomcat
execute: true
read: true
write: false
```

If I run similar code in a main method as the `tomcat` user

```
File logdir =  new File("/var/log/myapp");
    System.out.println("\n user: " + System.getProperty("user.name") +
        "\n execute: " + logdir.canExecute() +
        "\n read: " + logdir.canRead() +
        "\n write: " + logdir.canWrite()
        );
```

It prints that it has write permission

```
user: tomcat
execute: true
read: true
write: true
```

I've exhausted all the debugging that I know how to do.  What is preventing my web application from writing to this directory under tomcat 9? What do I need to do to fix it.

Comment: I don't know too much about coding for Tomcat, but you set `new File("/var/log/myapp")`, but created a directory: `/var/log/myapp/ drwxrwxr-x  tomcat tomcat`. Is Tomcat trying to write the **file** `myapp` instead of _into_ the **directory** `/var/log/myapp`?

Comment: I'm trying to create files in that directory and getting a permission denied error.   It appears to be because the directory is not writable.   However, it must be some restriction from within Tomcat itself, and something new in Tomcat 9.  I can  write to the directory just fine from outside Tomcat and I could do so from within the webapp under Tomcat 8.

Comment: Tomcat 9 is running smoothly on its own? Using the `tomcat` user and group? Only logging from inside your webapp doesn't work?

Comment: Correct.   Everything is running fine except logging from my webapp.  (I actually have several webapps and they all have the same problem of not being able to write each to their own log directory).  In fact the webapps themselves are running ok without logging.  They ignore the exceptions from logging and just don't write any logs.   It is making debugging a bit difficult though.

Comment: Could you try setting `export UMASK=0022` in your `setenv.sh` and restart Tomcat9?

Comment: I haven't used `setenv.sh` since tomcat7.   In tomcat 8 and 9, I put the settings that used to go in it into `/etc/default/tomcat9`

Comment: @Lenniey thanks for your help.  I found the issue from some other people posting about similar problems:  [Tomcat - User - migrate to tomcat 9: application can not write files on system filder](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/migrate-to-tomcat-9-application-can-not-write-files-on-system-filder-td5087140.html) and [How to allow Tomcat war app to write in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827735/how-to-allow-tomcat-war-app-to-write-in-folder)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by new systemd sandboxing around tomcat 9 as part of Debian/Ubuntu.   To solve the problem you need to tell systemd to allow read write access to additional directories for Tomcat.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d
echo -e "[Service]\nReadWritePaths=/var/log/" | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d/logging-allow.conf
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart tomcat9
```

After making these changes, web apps can once again write to their own directories in `/var/log`.

Source: [Debian Tomcat 9 release notes](https://salsa.debian.org/java-team/tomcat9/blob/master/debian/README.Debian)

Comment: OMG yes! I have been struggling with this one for a while. This post should rank higher in searches

Comment: You have just saved me after hours of debugging! Systemd at it again ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you're correct. I deleted my comment. I forgot that I also had to give the tomcat user permissions on the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Ostermiller's answer solves the problem.
Another way to do it would be:

```
systemctl edit tomcat9.service
```

put in

```
[Service]
ReadWritePaths=/var/log/
```

This will get written to /etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d/override.conf.
Then do

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart tomcat9.service
```

You can go back to the original with

```
systemctl revert tomcat9.service
```